# Tantalum capacitor reverse polarity

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, datasheet, polarity, tantalum

I have a datasheet for a part (TPS6735IDR) that shows application circuit examples where polarised capacitors are connected the wrong way around (positive terminal to ground). I thought this would cause them to blow up? Is the datasheet correct or have they made a mistake? Datasheet provided below:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps6735.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1621909192241&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fau.mouser.com%252F

The circuit that I mentioned is on page 12 (figure 15, application circuit).

Comment: Which cap do you think is backwards? The output is a negative voltage, so they all look correct to me.

Comment: Yeah nah I'm a bit sleep deprived ofc u guys are right. I just noticed this and was on my way back to say nvm :P

Answer (score 2):

That converter has a negative voltage output.

Comment: Yep, you're right - forgot abt the -ve output and just saw the positive of the cap connected to ground lol.